# spring tool suit not working properly with groovy eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite, groovy-eclipse

I am unable to make STS work correctly with the groovy eclipse plugin.

> Spring Tool Suite Version: 3.6.2.RELEASE
>
> Build Id: 201410091308
>
> Platform: Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.1)

It works properly until I install groovy plugin either from the STS dashboard or from the update site.
Installation finishes successfully. Error log is empty.
STS seems working, but some views like **Spring Explorer** or **Gradle Tasks** are not available anymore after plugin installation:

[image]

This views are also not available under **Window** -> **Show view** -> **Other...**
Starting STS with *-clean* flag did not help.
Pure eclipse with the STS plugin installed and GGTS experience the same issue.

Removal of the groovy eclipse plugin brings these views back.

Is there any way to make this stuff work together properly?

**UPDATE:** Looks like it is workspace related somehow. Everything seems working fine in case I switch to some other workspace location. Is there any way to normalize workspace metadata?

Comment: Can you provide a few steps how to reproduce this issue starting from a plain STS 3.6.2 installation?

Comment: Anything in the error log related to failure to create a view?